# What is the least distracting way to show some new information?

Tags: user-interface, text-editor, fullscreen

I'm working on an [editor for novel authors](http://sourceforge.net/projects/epen/). After seeing programs like [DarkRoom](http://www.techmalaya.com/2009/02/07/full-screen-text-editor-blogger/), I wanted to add an full screen mode. In addition to that, I'd like to offer an option to show information about characters and other relevant data as you type (so you don't have to grab the mouse just because you can't remember a detail about one of your characters). OTOH, it should not distract you from what you currently think.

For this, I need to know the least distracting way to show this new information. Can you point me to some research or examples for this? What is the opposite of the "blink" tag?

[EDIT] While the "press a key" solution would work, I'd still prefer a solution which feels like "the editor is actively trying to help/support me". I already know keywords which point to relevant information, so I was thinking to display that if the cursor stays for a few moments on a keyword. This should happen without any user interaction -- as if the software was reading the persons mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't looked into your app yet, but if you have any "notification area" (e.g. to the right ofthe menu bar):

When there is a "known name" under the text cursor, show e.g. `"Who is John? [F9]"` in a corner. Maybe display it / fade it in only when the cursor stays there for a few seconds, to avoid "corner of the eye activity" when just browsing. (The hotkey should work immediately, though)

With an active text selection, the same key might allow to create a new item. Indicating that functionality is a bit harder, as you don't have an idea that this is a name, and thre are probably many thing you can do to a selection.

Also, consider registering e.g. "Johnny" as an alternate name for John that references the same information.

Comment: How fast/slow should the fade be?

Comment: rather fast. Thinking about it, if it's tied to cursor movement, the delay is probably more mportant. One would have to experiment, but I'd start a delay of 1..2 seconds, and a 500ms fade. Maybe low contrast would be enough.

Comment: BTW. I tried to have a look at the app, to make a better fitting suggestion, but couldn't run it. I've added a case on SourceForge.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your idea, this feature is only for when the user is looking for some information. Why not use the standard shortcut for auto-completion in IDE (ctrl + space), and then display your data in a "tooltiptext way" ? This way, it won't bother you while you're writing, but then if you're looking for a piece of information, you don't have to look for it ; you juste press two keys and voilà. With this system, the problem of "how it's displayed" is really less important, no ?

**edit :** My point being : there is no better "non-distracting" way to show some information than displaying it only when requested.

Comment: I like this idea, though F1 might be a better choice for the shortcut as for most people that would already be associated with some form of help feature.

Comment: +1 for the general idea. I'll just keep the question open for some more time in case someone else comes up with something better.

Comment: @CurtainDog: I'd prefer the "details" key but I'm not sure which one that is. F1 is help, Ctrl+Space is word completion. F3 is more "go to details".

Comment: @CurtainDog: Don't use F1 for anything but help about an application itself. Help or rather additional information about the contents you are creating using an application do not fall into that category.